# Javascript Formatting UTC Date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Ok I have this exact date:

```
2012-10-01T13:00:00+0000
```

I need to split it into two variables: one is the date: **2012-10-01**, and the other is the time in hours and minutes: **13:00**

What I have so far produces **2012-09-12** & **14:00** - Completely the wrong date...

Here's the code:

```
var d, dd, hh, mi, mm, theDate, theTime, yyyy;

var myDate = "2012-10-01T13:00:00+0000"; //Date I need converting into two variables

d = new Date(myDate);

yyyy = d.getFullYear().toString();
mm = d.getMonth().toString();
dd = d.getDate().toString();
hh = d.getHours().toString();
mi = d.getMinutes().toString();


theDate = yyyy + "-" + (mm[1] ? mm : "0" + mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1] ? dd : "0" + dd[0]);
theTime = (hh[1] ? hh : "0" + hh[0]) + ":" + (mi[1] ? mi : "0" + mi[0]);

//theDate produces: 2012-09-12, (should be 2012-10-01)
//theTime produces: 14:00, (should be 13:00)
```

Comment: Use getUTCFullYear, getUTCMonth, getUTCDate, getUTCHours and getUTCMinutes. And remember that month is always 0-11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 1 to the month.

The time will adjust based on your local timezone. You are getting 14:00 because you are in GMT +1. Change time to 13:00:00+0100 to get the correct time.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:
month starts at 0 so +1
day takes the hour so your format is wrong.
Yous should print d to see what you actually constructed. Apart from that try:
[formatting the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605971/formatting-the-date-in-javascript?rq=1)